# Cant get openllet running on Fuseki

Tags: jena, semantic-web, fuseki, reasoning, pellet

yesterday i was trying to get Pellet and/or Openllet to run on my Fuseki Server.

Im am doing Requests over the Web-Interface. Without reasoners its working fine.

This is my configuration:

```
@prefix :      <http://base/#> .
@prefix tdb:   <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix ja:    <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .

<http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#DatasetTDB>
        rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

ja:DatasetTxnMem  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

tdb:GraphTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

<http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#GraphTDB2>
        rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

ja:MemoryDataset  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

ja:RDFDatasetZero  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

<http://jena.apache.org/text#TextDataset>
        rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

:service_tdb_all  a                   fuseki:Service ;
        rdfs:label                    "TDB FOOT" ;
        fuseki:dataset                :tdb_dataset_readwrite ;
        fuseki:name                   "FOOT" ;
        fuseki:serviceQuery           "query" , "" , "sparql" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore  "get" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadQuads       "" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore
                "data" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadWriteQuads  "" ;
        fuseki:serviceUpdate          "" , "update" ;
        fuseki:serviceUpload          "upload" .

:tdb_dataset_readwrite
        a             ja:RDFDataset;
        ja:defaultGraph       <#model_inf> ;
        tdb:location  "C:\\etc\\fuseki/databases/FOOT" .

<#model_inf> a ja:InfModel ;
     ja:baseModel <#graph> ;
     ja:reasoner [
        ja:reasonerClass "openllet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory";
     ] .

<#graph> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB ;
  tdb:dataset :tdb_dataset_readwrite .
```

Error-Log in the Tomcat Directory:

```
ERROR Exception in initialization: the class 'openllet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory' required by the object 7c374328cddba9fa8091dcebd77a7598 [ja:reasoner of file:///C:/etc/fuseki/configuration/FOOT.ttl#model_inf] could not be loaded
```

I had been copying the Openllet Jar-Files (openllet-query-2.6.5.jar and things) everywhere, but no chance.
Btw is this the right action anyway?!

In my Apache Jena project (and Snarp Sparql Protege Plugin) i got Openllet to run and it gets me the right results.

I got a few rules that are all of this type

```
                       [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                         owl:unionOf ( [ owl:intersectionOf ( [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                                owl:onProperty food:hasIngredient ;
                                                                owl:someValuesFrom food:Dairy
                                                              ]
                                                              [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                                owl:onProperty food:hasIngredient ;
                                                                owl:someValuesFrom [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                                                     owl:onProperty food:hasFood ;
                                                                                     owl:someValuesFrom food:Meat
                                                                                   ]
                                                              ]
                                                            ) ;
                                         rdf:type owl:Class
                                       ]
                                       [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                         owl:onProperty food:hasIngredient ;
                                         owl:someValuesFrom [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                              owl:onProperty food:hasFood ;
                                                              owl:someValuesFrom food:Pork
                                                            ]
                                       ]
                                     )
                       ]
                     ) ;
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                    owl:onProperty food:violatesRestriction ;
                    owl:hasValue food:kosherReligious
                  ]
] .
```

"Not kosher if there is pork in a recipe or meat in combination with a dairy product."

The reasoning is horrible slow (8 seconds on a 25000 triple database). If i extract the model before it runs fast but the **extraction of the model takes 3 minutes**.

I just want to have a way where the user can query recipes with the inferences of a reasoner in a reasonable time (< 2 seconds) :(

Are there any more (better?) reasoners who can work with **blank nodes** (Hermit cant...) ??

My questions are:

1. How can i get Fuseki to run with Pellet/Openllet
2. Reasoner alternatives?
3. Is there a better way to infer rules like the one above?
4. Am i completely wrong and do i have to let the reasoner to be run only one time at the start of the program and not for every query?

Best regards ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Openllet i tried the **OWLMicroFBRuleReasoner**, it **worked**! And its **fast**!

```
<#model_inf> a ja:InfModel ;
     ja:baseModel <#graph> ;
     ja:reasoner [
        ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/OWLMicroFBRuleReasoner>
     ] .
```

Comment: But why is the initial query after the server starts so slow? 40 secs and after it 3ms...